Asp.Net MVC -How does Javascript pick up a pasted Url and use it to test the Url via a button click
I'm using an Asp.net 6 MVC driven project. People submitting a video to a show are asked to paste the url and then click a button to test that the url works.  This is the code that collects the url:
<label class="control-label" style="font-size:12"><strong>Video Link </strong><small> [Paste link to URl, use Test Video Link to test that link works before </small></label>
<input asp-for ="VideoLink1" id="videolink1" type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Video Link - URL or Vimeo" style="font-size:medium">
<span asp-validation-for="VideoLink1" class="text-danger"></span>

<i class="fa fa-video"></i> <input name="testvideolink" class="btn btn-group-sm btn-info" id="testvideolink" style="font-size:smaller" value="Test Video Link" onclick="ViewURL()">

This is then picked up by script which should open the url in a separate web page:
function ViewURL() {
var url = document.getElementById('videolink1');
window.open(url, "_blank")

The simplest way to deal with this would be send it to the controller and then get the user to click the test button when it returns from the controller but this seems a bit clunky.  However, videolink1 does not have the url without running it through the controller.  I've tried various ways of trying to get the url name from the unsubmitted asp-for but have not found a way.

Not sure about what you are trying to achieve here and what is your question? Maybe use hidden form tag and store your videolink1 value there.

The user has just pasted the videolink1, I don't want to return to the controller but just want the javascript to pick up the value that has just been pasted.

This line: var url = document.getElementById('videolink1'); is doing that and getting you the value of the input. What do you want to do after that? I can see that you are opening the pasted link in a new tab.. I do not see anywhere in the code snippet that you are returning to the Controller. If you mean the validation is happening then that is a part of the annotations that you have placed. It has nothing to do with sending of data to the controller.

It does not get the value of the input.  When I click the button to run the ViewURL function I've inserted an alert and it is returning null even though the pasted Url is clearly showing on the page.

Try changing the id of your input element and see if that makes a difference. @RJP

Solved!  Changing the id name made no difference.  I was playing around and found that using .value was all I needed: var url = document.getElementById('videolink1');
window.open(url.value, "_blank");  I'm sure I tried this before without success but it now seems to work.

Ahh I see. I had missed that point entirely. I use JQuery so I get the value there using: $("#videolink1").val()
